# Add explicit source directory in jaxb2-maven-plugin for schemagen

Tags: maven, jaxb, jaxb2, maven-jaxb2-plugin, jaxb2-maven-plugin

I would like to generate schema from JAXB annotated classes. For this, I am using jaxb2-maven-plugin. The plugin by default scans src/main/java folder for included sources. I would like to specify an extra folder to scan for java classes which is not maven source path.

Can anyone please help?

```
  <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven.plugin.jaxb2}</version>
        <executions>
           <execution>
              <id>schemagen</id>
              <goals>
                 <goal>schemagen</goal>
              </goals>
              <phase>process-classes</phase>
              <configuration>

                 <includes>
                    <include>SomeFolderWhichIsNotInMavenSourcePath/*.java</include>
                 </includes>
                 <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/schemas</outputDirectory>
              </configuration>
           </execution>
        </executions>
     </plugin>
```

Comment: <include>${basedir}/whatever/**/*.java</include> ?

Comment: Nope, that does not work. The plugin looks by default in src/main/java folder. One way out is to add folder in maven source path which I dont want.

Answer (score 0):

Includes should be absolute paths to directories:

```
<includes>
    <include>${basedir}/src/main/java</include>
</includes>
```

You may run maven in debug mode to see which source directories are being used.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use *sources* instead of *includes*:

```
<sources>
   <source>${basedir}/src/main/java/<YourPath></source>
</sources>
```

In this way it will only scan the path you write between the sources tags.